# Kendo UI: Dynamically change dataSource of grid on button click event

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am having 2 Json files i.e. **Products.json** and **Promotions.json**. Both are having the same structure i.e. fields are same just the values are different.

When the page gets loaded the grid is bound with the data in **Products.json** as follows:

```
<!--dataSource gets the Products.json data -->
<div data-role="grid" data-columns="[{field:'code',title:'Code'} .... data-bind="source: dataSource"></div>
```

after which on button click I want to clear the current records of grid and add data of **Promotions.json**

```
<div data-role="grid" data-columns="[{field:'code',title:'Code'} .... data-bind="source: applyPromotionsDataSource"></div>
```

I am able to read both the dataSources successfully, also I am successfully able to get the "click" event as well..

**Questions**

1. How shall I clear the existing dataSource of the grid?
2. How shall I bind the new dataSource to the grid? (using what method?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for the above issue.

I went through the documentation of grid and came across the `setDataSource()` method and added it on the button click event.

That worked well.

Those looking into this issue, Thanks!! :)

-Hardik

Answer (score 2):

the method setDataSource() works well, but if datasource is different also in columns it goes on error cause it can't find the column "xxxNewDataSourceColumn"... There is a method to refresh also the columns?